# How can I implement the below design using any library in Android

Tags: android

[image]

The color of line will be changed

Comment: It is a Stepper view and link to one of the library : https://github.com/rakshakhegde/stepper-indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement it easily using Seekbar or this latest library

https://github.com/fython/MaterialStepperView

Answer (score 1):

Use Seekbar to achieve the above functionality.

`<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:max="3" android:tickMark="@drawable/tickmark" />`

For text, Create a LinearLayout above the seekbar with three TextViews and align it accordingly.